# Using linear algebra operations over a finite field in MuPad

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, matlab

When I try to use MuPad's linear algebra operations over a finite field, I receive the error 'An arithmetical expression is expected.' How should I go about doing this?

```
w := Dom::GaloisField(2, 2)(X1)
wbar := Dom::GaloisField(2, 2)(X1 + 1)
H := matrix([[0, 1, 1, 1, w, w], [0, w, 0, wbar, w, wbar], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
linalg::gaussJordan(H)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MuPad provides a separate function to create a matrix over a finite field. Use:

```
GF := Dom::GaloisField(2, 2);
w := GF::"variable";
wbar := w + 1;
H := Dom::Matrix(GF)([[0, 1, 1, 1, w, w], [0, w, 0, wbar, w, wbar], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]);
linalg::gaussJordan(H);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about finite fields, but, according to the R2016a [documentation for `Dom::GaloisField`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/dom-galoisfield.html), the combination of input arguments you're using is not supported. You also need to terminate each line with `;` or `:` if you're running these lines in one block. Maybe try:

```
w := Dom::GaloisField(2, 2, X1^2+X1+1)(X1):
wbar := Dom::GaloisField(2, 2, X1^2+X1+1)(X1 + 1):
H := matrix([[0, 1, 1, 1, w, w], [0, w, 0, wbar, w, wbar], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]);
```

However, you'll get another `Error: An arithmetical expression is expected. [normal]` when you run [`linalg::gaussJordan(H)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/linalg-gaussjordan.html). I believe this is because the function does not support matrices with abstract symbolic variables (`X1`), which makes sense.